# Java Scheduling: Quartz vs Others? (ie. Obsidian)

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I'm about to incorporate **Quartz** in one of our projects. While looking for a free UI to help us to monitor its execution state (jobs, etc.) we came across to this article: [why-you-shouldnt-use-quartz](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-you-shouldnt-use-quartz)

The author says Quartz is complex even for simple tasks (I tend to agree...) and mentions that [**Obsidian**](http://www.carfey.com/) is a better option, which includes a nice UI out of the box. Indeed, that UI is somehow better than the best free alternative I cold find for Quartz ([JWatch](http://code.google.com/p/jwatch/)).
Note: the author works for Obsidian...

- Does anybody recommends Obsidian over Quartz? (or any other alternative)?
- Do you know about any better free UI
  alternatives for Quartz?

Thanks,

Comment: Heck, I've been asking myself the same question. Does anybody have real-world experience using _both_ products? It'd be interesting to hear it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The program Quartz is the most widely used, however have a big problem because your Front End is very expensive.

But there are graphical applications for the quartz that can help in its analysis, such as JWatch [https://github.com/royrusso/jwatch](http://code.google.com/p/jwatch/) that has a graphical user interface on the web (as you have told before), Citrine [https://github.com/massdosage/citrine-scheduler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/citrine/), MyScheduler [https://github.com/saltnlight5/myschedule](http://code.google.com/p/myschedule/), Apache Click http://click.apache.org/ is a plugin for Eclipse that can help us systems installation, among other Front-End ...

Obsidian is quite good, with only one problem, you have to paid the second license, for a company is not the best solution, because the price, but for individuals is a great solution.